# On deriving a 'simple' formula for the taylor series of $\exp^{f(x_1,x_2)}$

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, power-series, exponential-function, bell-numbers

It is written explicitly in wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Generating_function, how one obtains a simple analytic expression for the Taylor series of the exponential of a function using Bell polynomials.

This formula gives schematically

$\exp^{f(x_1)-f(0)}=1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x_1^n}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}B_{n,k}(\partial_{x_1}f,\dots, \partial^{n-k+1}_{x_1}f)$.

It seems to me therefore that there should be a **relatively** simple way to write the analogous object for

$\exp^{f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n_1}{n!}\frac{x^m_2}{m!}(\cdots)$,

or otherwise some other user- friendly way to write out this expansion. **I am aware that one could do 1 variable expansion and then insert the second variable expansion into the Bell polynomials above, but it is not clear for me how to then simplify it further.**

I need this because I am comparing with a distinct object which equates to $G[x_1,x_2]=\exp^{f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)}$ and I would like to match powers of $x_1,x_2$ for the taylor expansions of G and f.

Any such friendly expressions would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: There are expansions in the “Exp from function” section in [Wolfram functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/9/) for the $n$th derivative. However, it requires finding $\frac{d^n g(x)^{m-j}}{dx^n}$